# Does this statement allow inheritance to properly work?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, subclass, multiple-inheritance

I'm doing a project on multilevel inheritance with a deck of playing cards. While working on the project, i received a compilation error in my program that was specifically for the suit classes (diamond.cpp, heart.cpp, etc.) constructor that stated

```
error: no matching function for call to 'RedCard::RedCard()'
```

I realized that this was because the RedCard and BlackCard clases did not have a default constructor. I was able to fix this by putting:

```
Heart::Heart(int v) : RedCard(v)
```

for the suit class constructor in order to specify the program to call the parametrized constructor rather than the non-existent default constructor.
I know that a class does not need to have a default constructor, and the class that a higher up class Card has a default constructor.

**My question is: does what I did allow inheritance to work?**

The heirarchy of the programs inheritance structure is here:

link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLSXi.jpg

[image: Text]

One thing I did notice while trying to finish the program, is that in my RedCard and BlackCard classes, there's a Description method we are to use. The switch statement that is in it uses throws an error saying that the "value" variable from the Card Class is inaccessible, so I presume I'm doing something wrong with the RedCard and BlackCard Classes.

***This is the Card.cpp file:***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "card.h"

Card::Card()  // Default Constructor: Initializes value to 0, color to "unknown", and suit to 'U'
{
  int value = 0;
  string color = "unknown";
  char suit = 'U';

} 

Card::Card(int v)  // Parameterized Constructor: Initializes value to v, color to "unknown", and suit to 'U'
{
  value = v; 
  color = "unknown";
  suit = 'U';
}  

int Card::GetValue() const  // Returns variable value
{
  return value;
}

string Card::GetColor() const  // Returns variable color
{
  return color;
}

char Card::GetSuit() const  // Returns variable suit
{
  return suit;
}

void Card::SetValue(int v)  // Sets value to v
{
  value = v;
}

void Card::SetColor(string c)
// Sets color to c
{
  color = c;
}

void Card::SetSuit(char s)
// Sets suit to s
{
  suit = s;
}


string Card::Description() const   // Outputs card characteristics - value as a string
// DO NOT MODIFY THIS METHOD !!!!
{
  string d = "Value = ";    // temporary variable used to accumulate result

  switch (value)            // Append card value to variable's value
  {
    case 2:   d = d + "2";    break;      // Number cards
    case 3:   d = d + "3";    break;
    case 4:   d = d + "4";    break;
    case 5:   d = d + "5";    break;
    case 6:   d = d + "6";    break;
    case 7:   d = d + "7";    break;
    case 8:   d = d + "8";    break;
    case 9:   d = d + "9";    break;
    case 10:  d = d + "10";   break;
    
    case 11:  d = d + "J";    break;      // Face cards
    case 12:  d = d + "Q";    break;
    case 13:  d = d + "K";    break;
    case 14:  d = d + "A";    break;

    default:  d = d + "?";    break;      // Unknown card
  }

  return d;                 // Return string describing card value
}
```

***This is the Card.h file***

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H

class Card                      // Class modeling Card ADT
{
 private:
  int value;                    // Card value: 2-10 for number cards, 11-14 for JQKA; 0 for unknown
  string color;                 // Card color: "red", "black", or "unknown"
  char suit;                    // Card suit: 'H' for hearts, 'D' for diamonds, 'C' for clubs, 'S' for spades or 'U' for unknown

 public:
  //******** Add Constructor Prototypes Below  *********//
  Card();      // Default constructor prototype: creates card with value 0, color unknown, and suit U
    
  Card(int v);      // Parameterized constructor prototype: creates card with value v, color unknown, and suit U
    
  //******** Add Transformer Prototypes Below *********//
  void SetValue(int v);      // SetValue prototype: Sets card value equal to v
  void SetColor(string c);      // SetColor prototype: Sets color value equal to c
  void SetSuit(char s);      // SetSuit prototype:  Sets suit value equal to s

  //******** Add Observer Prototypes Below *********//
  int GetValue() const;         // GetValue prototype: Returns current value of value
  string GetColor() const;      // GetColor prototype: Returns current value of color
  char GetSuit() const;     // GetSuit prototype:  Returns current value of suit
  string Description() const;      // Description prototype: Polymorphic Function!!!
                                // Outputs card characteristics - value as a string (see sample output from p01input1.txt)
};
#endif
```

***The blackcard.cpp file is here and is the same for redcard.cpp: ***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "blackcard.h"

BlackCard::BlackCard(int v)
{

}
string BlackCard::Description() const
{
    string d = "Value = ";    // temporary variable used to accumulate result

    switch (value)            // Append card value to variable's value
    {

    case 2:   d = d + "2";    break;      // Number cards
    case 3:   d = d + "3";    break;
    case 4:   d = d + "4";    break;
    case 5:   d = d + "5";    break;
    case 6:   d = d + "6";    break;
    case 7:   d = d + "7";    break;
    case 8:   d = d + "8";    break;
    case 9:   d = d + "9";    break;
    case 10:  d = d + "10";   break;
    
    case 11:  d = d + "J";    break;      // Face cards
    case 12:  d = d + "Q";    break;
    case 13:  d = d + "K";    break;
    case 14:  d = d + "A";    break;

    default:  d = d + "?";    break;      // Unknown card  
    }
  return d;                 // Return string describing card value
}
```

An example file for what my original issue above is heart.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "heart.h"

Heart::Heart(int v) : RedCard(v)
{

}

string Heart::Description() const
{
    string d = "Value = ";    // temporary variable used to accumulate result
    
    switch (value)            // Append card value to variable's value
    {
        
    case 2:   d = d + "2";    break;      // Number cards
    case 3:   d = d + "3";    break;
    case 4:   d = d + "4";    break;
    case 5:   d = d + "5";    break;
    case 6:   d = d + "6";    break;
    case 7:   d = d + "7";    break;
    case 8:   d = d + "8";    break;
    case 9:   d = d + "9";    break;
    case 10:  d = d + "10";   break;
    
    case 11:  d = d + "J";    break;      // Face cards
    case 12:  d = d + "Q";    break;
    case 13:  d = d + "K";    break;
    case 14:  d = d + "A";    break;

    default:  d = d + "?";    break;      // Unknown card
    
    }

  return d;                 // Return string describing card value
}
```

I aplogize in advance for the length of the question and if anything is missing. It's a rather large project and the issue is hard to describe with how manny files are involved.

Please let me know if i'm needing to clarify anything. I appreciate any advice and your time.

Comment: Your "fix" allows your code to compile, by explicitly ensuring an existing constructor is called rather than getting a diagnosable error due to trying to call a non-existent constructor.     It's impossible to say if that is necessary for inheritance to "properly work", since that can mean many things, depending on what requirements your program is required to meet.

Comment: There's a huge amount of unnecessary (as far as I can see) code duplication, like the `Description` methods. You can use `+=` with `std::string` which might make your code a bit more readable and efficient.

Comment: Hint: one of the main benefits of inheritance is the ability to make reusable classes for common features. Note that you define `Description` in `Card`, `RedCard`, and `Heart`. That is not what you want. You probably only need `Description` in `Card`. Inherit `Card` in `RedCard` (not sure what you need that one for, maybe just a field defining the color), then inherit `RedCard` in `Heart`. As Peter points out, there are many flavors of inheritance, depending on what you are doing.

Comment: @RetiredNinja So that was an oversight on my part, but there are different variations of the ```Description``` class that changes for RedCard, Card, Heart, etc. I did not alter it in the version I posted however.

Comment: One question I have is how I would go about inheriting the Base class's parametrized constructor into the RedCard and BlackCard programs? I included the Card.h file in both of them but I can't figure out how to properly interact with them. If I try to use the value from the base class it throws an error and says it's inaccessible.

Comment: Well, you already know how to call the base class constructor from the derived class constructor. You have this in your code: `Heart::Heart(int v) : RedCard(v) {}` . `RedCard` could call the constructor of `Card` the same way.

Comment: As your question is about constructors and inheritance, you might remove from the question all other methods.